# cases in align produces errors with Scientific Word-exported file

Tags: align, cases

For some reason I have to edit a tex file exported from Scientific Word, which has the line

```
\input{tcilatex}
```

I downloaded `tcilatex.tex` from [here](http://www.cs.rit.edu/usr/local/pub/pga/LaTeX/tcilatex.tex). However, everything works fine until I try to use `cases` environment inside an `align`, or `align*`.

A toy example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\input{tcilatex}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  a = \begin{cases}
    b\\c
  \end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this file gives a lot of errors...

I noticed in the file I am editting, it seems Scientific Word has avoided the `align` environment and uses `eqnarray` which is [advised as inferior](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align).

Is this problem reproducible for you? If yes, what can be done to solve this problem? If not, what is the correct `tcilatex.tex` I should get?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't know much about SWP, but from what I can see `tcilatex.tex` redefines several macros from `amsmath`, so they cause conflicts.

Comment: Do you actually need `tcilatex`? As @egreg points out, much of it seems to be definitions of macros from `amsmath`. I suggest commenting out `\input{tcilatex}`. Then copy and paste any parts that are required into the preamble of your document.

Comment: @IanThompson -- make that an answer, please

Comment: @barbarabeeton --- done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @egreg points out in the comments, most of `tcilatex.tex` seems to be definitions of macros from the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). Now the amsmath package is used more or less universally for documents that contain a lot of mathematics, so including a file that conflicts with it is not a good idea. Therefore I suggest removing `\input{tcilatex}`, which fixes your example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\input{tcilatex}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  a = \begin{cases}
    b\\c
  \end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

If your actual document generates `Undefined control sequence` errors with `amsmath` but no `tcilatex`, just copy the definitions of the missing macros into the preamble.